# How to get dropdown value as a textbox name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/t12x9boj/

```
<select id="drop" name="1" class="form-control">
  <option value="policy_no">Policy No</option>
  <option value="claim_no">Claim No</option>
  <option value="acc_no">Account No</option>
  <option value="client_no">Client No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="selectValue">
```

for example, if user selected **Policy No** from dropdown, the code textbox code statement become `<input type="text" name="policy_no">`

or if user select **Claim No** then `<input type="text" name="claim_no">`

**SOLUTIONS**
by @NewToJS

```
<select id="drop" name="1" class="form-control" onchange="setname(this.value)">
<option value="policy_no">Policy No</option>
<option value="claim_no">Claim No</option>
<option value="acc_no">Account No</option>
<option value="client_no">Client No</option>
</select>
<input id="dropvalue" type="text" name="selectValue" onclick="this.value='';alert(this.name);"> 

function setname(e){
var input=document.getElementById('dropvalue');
input.name=e;
input.value="Click Me!";
}
```

**SOLUTIONS** by @Milan Chheda

```
$("#drop").on('change', function() {
  $("#inputId").prop('name', $(this).val());
  //2nd method
  //$("#inputId").attr('name', $(this).val()); 
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop" name="1" class="form-control">
  <option value="policy_no">Policy No</option>
  <option value="claim_no">Claim No</option>
  <option value="acc_no">Account No</option>
  <option value="client_no">Client No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="selectValue" id='inputId'>
```

Comment: Use jQuery on select value to set name of textbox

Comment: Why would you tag PHP for it?

Comment: thats the hard part...I tried searching on the net but cannot find any similar problem

Comment: @MilanChheda for web development

Comment: Bind `change` event on `<select>`, get the selected value by using `val()` and update attribute using `attr()` method.

Comment: @learnprogramming I see someone has posted a `jQuery` solution but this can be done without the need for `jQuery`. Nothing wrong with using it but if you load the library for such little use as this then it's no doubt best to keep it simple. Here is a non-jQuery solution you could try something as simple as this [**JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ob8dw5g/)

Comment: brb let me try the codes

Comment: i have tried your code, it does changed the txtbox name but i the data is not stored according to the txtbox name

Comment: @learnprogramming The demo shows it clearly works. How are you submitting the data? Via a form posting to another page or are you using ajax? Your question is lacking information hence very basic answers being given. I would also recommend you open the browser console while using javascript to view any/all error reports if any are to occur.

Comment: lol yeah it really works! but i have to click somewhere else that are not clickable(empty/white space) after i entered the value in the textbox...that way, i can store the data...not sure why this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jquery `prop` to achieve this. You need to inspect and check the `name` attribute of `input` while changing the dropdown options:

```js
$("#drop").on('change', function() {
  $("#inputId").prop('name', $(this).val());
  //2nd method
  //$("#inputId").attr('name', $(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop" name="1" class="form-control">
  <option value="policy_no">Policy No</option>
  <option value="claim_no">Claim No</option>
  <option value="acc_no">Account No</option>
  <option value="client_no">Client No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="selectValue" id='inputId'>
```

Comment: brb, let me try this

Comment: after ive tried your codes, i'm not sure why only the first value, policy_no, was key-ed into table columns but not the other values...when i checked in the inspection, the textbox name is changed accordingly when the selectbox is changed

Comment: Check the value before sending it to your server. Alternatively, instead of `prop('name', $(this).val());`, may be, we can also use and you can try `attr('name', $(this).val());`

Comment: im sorry..actually the first method works, but i have to click somewhere else that are not clickable(empty/white space) after i entered the value in the textbox...that way, i can store the data...not sure why this happen

Comment: That shouldn't really happen unless you have some event or JS code for the textbox that might be conflicting and/or forcing you to click on the empty space.